# Linear vs Exponential growth

Tags: algebra-precalculus, exponentiation

I'm doing some exercises and I had this one:

[image: exponential table]

Obviously, it's an exponential table since $y$ gets multiplied by $3$ every time.
But if its exponential and the exponent is $x$ wouldn't an exponent of $x=0$ be equal to $y=1$, and if $x=1$ then $y=3$ because of exponential rules?

Comment: You're right that it's exponential. If you need a formula try $y = 2 \times 3^x$.

Comment: Doesn't really answer my question tho., Ethan, does it.. ;)

Comment: @AaronMontgomery has spelled out why my comment is (essentially) an answer to your question.

Comment: Yeah I didn't know that a table of "exponential growth" doesn't have to follow the $y=c^x$ formula. Now I do, so thanks, I appreciate any input that I get.

Comment: You're welcome. Do accept (and upvote) his answer.

Comment: I did, but there is this time limit that requires you to wait out the full 15 minutes before choosing the best answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Exponential growth" doesn't require the data to follow $y = c^x$; it permits an additional constant multiplier, such as $y = a \cdot c^x$. This is similar in spirit to how linear growth does not require $y = m \cdot x$, but also permits an additive term via $y = m \cdot x + b$.